# gimp not loading in acer aspire es1-512 notebook

Tags: acer, gimp, aspire

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my new lap of Acer Aspire ES1-512. When i try to open Gimp 2.8, it is not loading. It hangs. Please help me.

Comment: GIMP can take a bit of time to load the first time, especially on weaker systems. Just wait.

Comment: The step that takes an especially long time on the initial run is the font cache creation.

Answer (score 0):

Launch a terminal and type

```
gimp --verbose
```

This way you can see what is going on and if an error happens.  Or if it is really just taking forever like was suggested.